# Stop While Not when the correct answer is found

Tags: asp-classic

I've got a table with six records, so far. Everyone has 2 fields: Min_lenght, Max_lenght. 
Those field define a range, so the first item has Min_lenght = 160, Max_lenght = 179 and so on.
When defining 1 value (custom_lenght) I need to stop the SQL when this values is in range. 
So (custom_lenght > Min_lenght) AND (custom_lenght < Max_lenght)

```
custom_lenght = cint(request("custom_lenght"))
Set objRS2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_model where Order by ID_model ASC"
objRS2.Open sql2, ConString
If Not objRS2.EOF Then
While Not objRS2.EOF
Min_lenght = cint(objRS2("Min_lenght"))
Max_lenght = cint(objRS2("Max_lenght"))
order = objRS2("order")
Price = objRS2("price") 
if (custom_lenght > Min_lenght ) AND (custom_lenght < Max_lenght) then
Outofrange="True"
else
Outofrange = "False"  
End If
objRS2.MoveNext
Wend
End If
PuliziaRS(objRS2)
```

The problem is, the SQL browse all the records. I need to obtain the data (price and order) of the item that falls between the range

Answer (score 1):

Change your SQL statement to `"SELECT order, price FROM tbl_model WHERE (Min_length < " & custom_length & " AND Max_length > " & custom_length & ") ORDER BY ID_Model"`

This will limit the recordset to records that match your custom_length.

Comment: You may have to use <= and/or >= depending on what results exactly you want to obtain.

Comment: Always worth a mention: use parameterized queries rather than concatenation. `... WHERE Min_length < ? AND ...`. Concatenation can be a huge security hole

Answer (score 0):

As a alternative;

```
custom_lenght = cint(request("custom_lenght"))
Set objRS2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql2 = "SELECT order, price FROM tbl_model WHERE " & custom_lenght & " BETWEEN Min_lenght AND Max_lenght Order by ID_model ASC"
objRS2.Open sql2, ConString
If Not objRS2.EOF Then
    order = objRS2("order")
    Price = objRS2("price")
    Outofrange = "True"
Else
    Outofrange = "False"  
End If
objRS2.Close
```